# Класс с аргументами как аргумент в функции

Tags: python, ооп, функции, классы, аргументы

Всем привет! Есть одна функция которая принимает класс как аргумент, но у этого класса нельзя вызвать аргументы самого класса, а если я вызову класс вместе с аргументами, произойдёт ошибка `TypeError: 'SubProcessor' object is not callable`, код:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class SubProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, getRoutes, postRoutes): # сами аргументы в __init__
        print(getRoutes, postRoutes)

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        

class Sub:
    def __init__(self):
        self.getRoutes = []
        self.postRoutes = []

    def get(self, route):
        def getWrapper(func):
            self.getRoutes.append({'route': route, 'func': func})
        return getWrapper

    def post(self, route):
        def postWrapper(func):
            self.postRoutes.append({'route': route, 'func': func})
        return postWrapper

    def serve(self, port):
        self.server = HTTPServer(("", 8080), SubProcessor(self.getRoutes, self.postRoutes)) # мне нужно передать в класс аргументы
        self.server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Передавать не обязательно именно класс. Достаточно передать что-то, что сконструирует его объект, например функцию. Только не забудьте проинициализировать базовый класс обработчика.

```py
from functools import partial

class SubProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, getRoutes, postRoutes):
        super().__init__(*args)
        print(getRoutes, postRoutes)

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

class Sub:
    ...
    def serve(self, port):
        self.server = HTTPServer(("", 8080),
                                 partial(SubProcessor,
                                         getRoutes=self.getRoutes,
                                         postRoutes=self.postRoutes))
        self.server.serve_forever()
```

Также можно объявить класс прямо в методе

```
    def serve(self, port):
        class SubProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
            #            Здесь self: SubProcessor
            #            V                      а здесь                    и здесь self: Sub
            def __init__(self, *args, getRoutes=self.getRoutes, postRoutes=self.postRoutes):
                super().__init__(*args)
                print(getRoutes, postRoutes)

            def do_GET(self):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                self.end_headers()

        self.server = HTTPServer(("", 8080), SubProcessor)
        self.server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

я не знаю как у вас вызываются методы `get`, `post`, `serve`,  поэтому я их вызвал в лоб. Попробуйте:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class SubProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, getRoutes, postRoutes):                        # сами аргументы в __init__
        
        self.getRoutes =  getRoutes 
        self.postRoutes = postRoutes
        print(f'\n >>> {self.getRoutes}, {self.postRoutes}')          # !

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        

class Sub:
    def __init__(self):
        self.getRoutes = []
        self.postRoutes = []
        
        self.get(route='route123')                                    # !
        print(f'getRoutes  -> {self.getRoutes}')
        self.post(route='route789')                                   # !
        print(f'postRoutes -> {self.postRoutes}')
        self.serve(port='8080')                                       # !

    def get(self, route):
        def getWrapper(func):
            #print(f'func       -> `{func}`')
            self.getRoutes.append({'route': route, 'func': func})
#        return getWrapper
        return getWrapper('func123')                                  # !

    def post(self, route):
        def postWrapper(func):
            self.postRoutes.append({'route': route, 'func': func})
#        return postWrapper
        return postWrapper('func789')                                 # !

    def serve(self, port): 
        #                                          # мне нужно передать в класс аргументы
        self.server = HTTPServer(("", 8080), SubProcessor(self.getRoutes, self.postRoutes)) 
        self.server.serve_forever()


sub = Sub()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]